# Could not attach to pid : “41851”?

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, xcode7.3

When running app in iOS simulator through Xcode 7.3. It's giving error with message - Could not attach to pid : “41851”.

Comment: Take a look in ~/Library/Logs/CoreSimulator/[UDID]/system.log to see what the underlying problem is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I reseted the simulator and it worked fine. I think that's the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this in the terminal:

```
sudo DevToolsSecurity -enable
```

Answer (score -1):

Reset the content and settings in the simulator. This is available in the "`iOS Simulator`" menu.